# Extjs TreePanel with grouping

Tags: javascript, user-interface, extjs, extjs4.1

Is it possible in ExtJs 4.1 to use TreePanel with grouping feature? Since in this case i have to use TreeStore, which doesn't contain "groupField" property, instead of regular Ext.Data.Store, i just have no idea how to enable grouping.

Comment: Why you want a grouping feature since a treepanel is basically a gridpanel with a build-in grouping feature?

Comment: Because i already have threepanel with its folder style grouping, but i also need different style grouping, that provides Ext.grid.feature.Grouping. But, im afraid, it is too much to ask

Comment: Hi Baychurin..did you succeed in enabling grouping for tree store?

Answer (score 0):

Try configuring tableview's store:

```
tree.getView().getStore().group([{property: 'groupField'}])
```

Add this for example to afterrendel listener of your tree.
Also you should enable grouping feature on this tree panel as usual.